# Not able to install robot framework on Jython

Tags: robotframework, jython

I'm new to robot framework with appium using Eclipse with RED editor

I'm trying to install robot framework on jython using this command

C:\Users\Uday>jython -m pip install robotframework

But I'm getting below error

[33mDEPRECATION: A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.←[0m

Collecting robotframework

←[31m  ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'))}←[0m

←[33m  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)': /simple/robotframework/←[0m

←[31m  ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'))}←[0m

←[33m  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)': /simple/robotframework/←[0m

←[31m  ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'))}←[0m

←[33m  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)': /simple/robotframework/←[0m

←[31m  ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'))}←[0m

←[33m  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)': /simple/robotframework/←[0m

←[31m  ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'))}←[0m

←[33m  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)': /simple/robotframework/←[0m

←[31m  ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'))}←[0m

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/robotframework/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/robotframework/ (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)) - skipping

←[31m  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework (from versions: none)←[0m

←[31mERROR: No matching distribution found for robotframework←[0m

←[31mERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'))}←[0m

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)) - skipping

Can anyone please help here

Answer (score 0):

I have faced that same issue, and one way around it is to install directly from the GitHub release.

For `robotframework`, it appears that version [4.1.2](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/releases/tag/v4.1.2) is the last release that supports [J/P]ython 2.7, so you would install it by running the following command:

```sh
jython -m pip install https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/archive/refs/tags/v4.1.2.zip
```

And that should do it.